# Programmatically zooming, panning a UIWebView for iPhone 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, event-handling, uiwebview

Greetings!

I'm trying to have a UIWebView controlled from generated events.

Is there a part of the **documented** iphone SDK to programatically create a UIEvent (or action or something) that I can then pass to a UIWebView and have it interpret it like a user's gesture?

I'd settle just if somebody could show me or link to just creating a pinch event!

Or if anybody knows WHY this is impossible or only accomplished in someway that violates the license that would also be helpful...

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no documented method to create a `UIEvent`, you can intercept and resend `UIEvent`s by implementing `-sendEvent:` in a custom `UIApplication` subclass.

Using private methods you can call `[[UIEvent alloc] _initWithTouches:(NSMutableSet *)touches keyedTouches:NULL]` to get a new `UIEvent`

If you are looking to specifically set the zoom level on a `UIWebView` the documented way would be to do so via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [bromine](http://code.google.com/p/bromine/) on google code. It generates touch events as part of the test process.